# Sleep / pause a function in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am making an app for wp 7.x/8.

There is a function like -

```
public void draw()
{
    .............
    ImageBrush imgbrush = new ImageBrush();
    imgbrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(...);

    rect.Fill = imgbrush;  //rect is of type Rectangle that has been created 
                           //and added to the canvas
    ........
}
```

and another function

```
private void clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    draw();
    ........
    if (flag)
    {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          draw();
    }
}
```

But when the button is clicked the result of both the draw operation appear simultaneously on the screen.

How to make the result of second draw() operation to appear after some delay?

Or is there something like buffer for the screen, until the buffer is not filled the screen will not refresh?

In that case, how to FLUSH or Refresh the screen explicitly or force the .fill() method of Rectangle to make the changes on the screen?

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the delay? Maybe make it a stupid high number to start with then tweak it down?

Comment: I don't know why this is ocurring, but it is generally not a good idea to freeze your main UI thread.  Why don't you fire off an async timer of some sorts?

Comment: You have not collected your draawing code in the OnPaint() method. This would provide access to the Invalidate(), Refresh(), and Update() methods of the form to control aspects of painting. Manual (and automated) double-buffering is easily done, but I am not sure yet if you requrie it.

Comment: @LeorA how to start an async timer ?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I have 2-3 functions for drawing different items on the screen, I cannot put them all in one single OnPaint() method. can you tell any alternate.

Comment: @acbruptenda: Yes; its called an IF ... ELSE ... statement.

Answer (score 1):

As pantaloons says, since all of your actions are on the same thread (the first draw, the sleep, and the second draw), the UI itself never gets a chance to update.  However, there is a slightly better implementation (though it follows the same principal as the aforementioned suggestion).

By using a timer, you can let it kick the wait to another thread, allowing the UI to update from the first draw before doing the second, like so:

```
private void clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    draw();
    ........
    if (flag)
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };

        timer.Tick += (sender, args) => { timer.Stop(); draw(); };

        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

In this solution, all the invocation is handled by the DispatcherTimer (which will automatically call back to the UI thread).  Also, if draw needs to be called more than twice in a row, the timer will continue to tick until stopped, so it would be very straightforward to extend to include a count.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are blocking the UI thread by sleeping, so the draw messages are never pumped until that function returns, where the changes happen synchronously. A hacky solution would be something like the following, although really you should change your app design to use the async/await patterns.

```c#
private void clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    draw();
    if (flag)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                draw();
            });
        });
    }
}
```